# python os.chroot : unexpected output after exiting chroot

Tags: python, chroot

I have the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import os
import subprocess

def run_subprocess(cmd):
    print 'Starting : {}'.format(cmd)
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) 
    odata, edata = p.communicate()
    print 'Done : {}'.format(cmd)
    if odata:
        print 'Output : {}'.format(odata)
    if edata:
        print 'Error : {}'.format(edata)
    return odata

LS_CMD = 'ls'
run_subprocess(LS_CMD)  # output 1
x_cwd = os.getcwd()
root_fd =os.open('/', os.O_RDONLY)
os.chroot('/mnt/mnt_sda5')
os.chdir('/')
os.fchdir(root_fd)
os.close(root_fd)
os.chdir(x_cwd)
run_subprocess(LS_CMD)  # output 2
print os.getcwd()
```

I chroot into a different directory and came back to the present working directory.

I was expecting both output1 and output2 matching. The output1 is what I expect to see. The output2 is empty.

Could you please explain the reason why ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Immediately before your `os.chdir(x_cwd)` you need `os.chroot('.')` to change the root back to the original '/' path that you've now changed to with fchdir. So those lines become:

```
os.fchdir(root_fd)
os.chroot('.')
os.close(root_fd)
```

There are some detail on this here - http://www.bpfh.net/simes/computing/chroot-break.html

Comment: In python do I need the os.chdir('/') after os.chroot('/mnt/mnt_sda5').
Does it matter if it is before or after it.

Comment: Answering my own question. In python we need it. 
A os.getcwd() outputs unreachable if we do not have os.chdir('/)